# Why does JSONTokener/Object keep randomizing my json data?

Tags: java, android, json, string

I've been trying to debug this problem for hours and have Googled it and can't even find someone who's having the same problem. For some reason JSONObject/JSONTokener is doing bizarre things.

The following code:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(sourceJson).nextValue();

Log.d(" ", sourceJson + "\n");
Log.d(" ", jsonObj.toString());
```

Produces this output:

```
{
    "2012":{
        "federal":[[10822,0.15],[42707,0.22],[85414,0.26],[132406,0.29]],
        "provincial":{
            "AB":[[17282,0.1]],
            "BC":[[11354,0.0506],[37013,0.077],[74028,0.105],[84993,0.1229],[103205,0.147]],
            "MB":[[8634,0.108],[31000,0.1275],[67000,0.174]],
            "NB":[[9203,0.091],[38190,0.121],[76380,0.124],[124178,0.143]],
            "NL":[[8237,0.077],[32893,0.125],[65785,0.133]],
            "NS":[[8481,0.0879],[29590,0.1495],[59180,0.1667],[93000,0.175],[150000,0.21]],
            "NT":[[13280,0.059],[38679,0.086],[77360,0.122],[125771,0.1405]],
            "NU":[[12211,0.04],[40721,0.07],[81442,0.09],[132406,0.115]],
            "ON":[[9405,0.0505],[39020,0.0915],[78043,0.1116],[500000,0.1216]],
            "PE":[[7708,0.098],[31984,0.138],[63969,0.167]],
            "QC":[[10925,0.16],[40100,0.2],[80200,0.24]],
            "SK":[[14942,0.11],[42065,0.13],[120185,0.15]],
            "YT":[[10822,0.0704],[42707,0.0968],[85414,0.1144],[132406,0.1276]]
        }
    }
}

{"2012":{"provincial":{"ON":[[9405,0.0505],[39020,0.0915],[78043,0.1116],[500000,0.1216]],"AB":[[17282,0.1]],"BC":[[11354,0.0506],[37013,0.077],[74028,0.105],[84993,0.1229],[103205,0.147]],"NL":[[8237,0.077],[32893,0.125],[65785,0.133]],"QC":[[10925,0.16],[40100,0.2],[80200,0.24]],"NU":[[12211,0.04],[40721,0.07],[81442,0.09],[132406,0.115]],"SK":[[14942,0.11],[42065,0.13],[120185,0.15]],"PE":[[7708,0.098],[31984,0.138],[63969,0.167]],"NT":[[13280,0.059],[38679,0.086],[77360,0.122],[125771,0.1405]],"NS":[[8481,0.0879],[29590,0.1495],[59180,0.1667],[93000,0.175],[150000,0.21]],"YT":[[10822,0.0704],[42707,0.0968],[85414,0.1144],[132406,0.1276]],"NB":[[9203,0.091],[38190,0.121],[76380,0.124],[124178,0.143]],"MB":[[8634,0.108],[31000,0.1275],[67000,0.174]]},"federal":[[10822,0.15],[42707,0.22],[85414,0.26],[132406,0.29]]}}
```

The nicely formatted data above is identical to the data.json file that I used to populate `sourceJson` and the very long line has had the order of the provinces mysteriously rearranged (but not the data within each province's 2D array).

I've also tried:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(sourceJson); // same problem
```

and

```
JSONTokener jsonTk = new JSONTokener(sourceJson);
Log.d(" ", jsonTk.toString()); // result = " at character 0 of " + sourceJson;

Log.d(" ", jsonTk.nextValue().toString()); // output same as original problem
```

I also tried to using a breakpoint to trace the call to `nextValue()` but couldn't find the cause of the problem. The behavior suggests that the JSONObject(String) constructor may call nextValue(), since both methods give the same output.

**So the question is:** Does anyone know why JSONObject/JSONTokener.nextValue() behaves this way? And, more importantly, do you know how to get it to parse the JSON data without reorganizing it? (I need to iterate through the data, even if the data file changes in the future)

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON objects (nodes) **are not ordered**. It is definition of json format. In Java are JSON nodes implemented as HashMap and HashMap is not ordered too.

If you really need something ordered in JSON, you need to use JSON Array. Example:

```
{
"2012":{
    "federal":[[10822,0.15],[42707,0.22],[85414,0.26],[132406,0.29]],
    "provincial":{
["code":"AB", data:[[17282,0.1]]],
["code":"BC", data:[[11354,0.0506],[37013,0.077],[74028,0.105],[84993,0.1229],[103205,0.147]]],
["code":"MB", data:[[8634,0.108],[31000,0.1275],[67000,0.174]]]
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes more sense, now. Realizing that I can't do it the way I intended caused me to come up with a better solution within minutes (it's funny how things work, sometimes) so again, Thank you! :)